# remove non ascii characters from csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, unicode, ascii

I am trying to remove non-ascii characters from a file. I am actually trying to convert a text file which contains these characters (eg. hello§‚å½¢æˆ äº†å¯¹æ¯”ã€‚ èŠ±å) into a csv file.

However, I am unable to iterate through these characters and hence I want to remove them (i.e chop off or put a space). Here's the code (researched and gathered from various sources)

The problem with the code is, after running the script, the csv/txt file has not been updated. Which means the characters are still there. Have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this anymore. Researched for a day :(

Would kindly appreciate your help!

```
import csv

txt_file = r"xxx.txt"
csv_file = r"xxx.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))
for row in in_txt:
    for i in row:
        i = "".join([a if ord(a)<128 else''for a in i])

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: Because you never update `in_txt` (the content that you're outputting to the csv. `i` is a **copy** of the row, it's not a pointer to the original row in `in_txt`

Comment: Strings are immutable in python and assignment does not mutate a value in place, it reassigns the name to reference the now assigned object. So as @Torxed pointed out, you never actually update anything.

Comment: hey @Torxed and ilja, sorry for sounding stupid but, I thought by 'updating' the i, I have already updated in_txt?
May I ask how to update in_txt?

Comment: @Bread Either you would need to use `out_csv.write(...)` for each `for row` loop, or you'd have to save each row in a output buffer that you write instead of `in_txt`, the later being the better performance and disk IO wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable assignment is not magically transferred to the original source; you have to build up a new list of your changed rows:

```
import csv

txt_file = r"xxx.txt"
csv_file = r"xxx.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))
out_txt = []
for row in in_txt:
    out_txt.append([
        "".join(a if ord(a) < 128 else '' for a in i)
        for i in row
    ]

out_csv.writerows(out_txt)
```