# How do I deal with non ascii character from CSV when using json.loads in Python?

Tags: python, json, unicode

I looked at some answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457277/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv-file-using-python) but none seem to answer my question.

Here are some example lines from CSV:

```
_id category
ObjectId(56266da778d34fdc048b470b)  [{"group":"Home","id":"53cea0be763f4a6f4a8b459e","name":"Cleaning Services","name_singular":"Cleaning Service"}]
ObjectId(56266e0c78d34f22058b46de)  [{"group":"Local","id":"5637a1b178d34f20158b464f","name":"Balloon Dí©cor","name_singular":"Balloon Dí©cor"}]
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import sys

from sys import argv
import json


def ReadCSV(csvfile):
with open('newCSVFile.csv','wb') as g:
    filewriter = csv.writer(g) #, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # ceate reader object
        next(reader) # skip first row

        for row in reader: #go trhough all the rows
            listForExport = [] #initialize list that will have two items: id and list of categories

            # ID section
            vendorId = str(row[0]) #pull the raw vendor id out of the first column of the csv
            vendorId = vendorId[9:33] # slice to remove objectdId lable and parenthases
            listForExport.append(vendorId) #add evendor ID to first item in list


            # categories section
            tempCatList = []  #temporarly list of categories for scond item in listForExport

            #this is line 41 where the error stems
            categories = json.loads(row[1]) #create's a dict with the categoreis from a given row

            for names in categories:  # loop through the categorie names using the key 'name'

                print names['name']
```

Here's what I get:

```
Cleaning Services
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvtesting.py", line 57, in <module>
    ReadCSV(csvfile)
  File "csvtesting.py", line 41, in ReadCSV
    categories = json.loads(row[1]) #create's a dict with the categoreis from a given row
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10: invalid continuation byte
```

So the code pulls out the fist category `Cleaning Services`, but then fails when we get to the non ascii characters.

How do I deal with this?  I'm happy to just remove any non-ascii items.

Comment: Have you tried `your_string.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')`?

Comment: No. Where in the code would I put that?

Comment: I guess in this case, `your_string` is simply `names['name']`.

Comment: don't you have to pass delimeter=' ' in csv.reader ?

Comment: @Coldspeed the error stems from two lines above `categories = json.loads(row[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you open the input csv file in `rb` mode, I assume that you are using a Python2.x version. The good news is that you have no problem in the csv part because the csv reader will read plain bytes without trying to interpret them. But the `json` module will insist in decoding the text into unicode and by default uses utf8. As your input file is not utf8 encoded is chokes and raises a UnicodeDecodeError.

Latin1 has a nice property: the unicode value of any byte is just the value of the byte, so you are sure to decode anything - whether it makes sense then depend of actual encoding being  Latin1...

So you could just do:

```
categories = json.loads(row[1], encoding="Latin1")
```

Alternatively, if you want to ignore non ascii characters, you could first convert the byte string to unicode ignoring errors and only then load the json:

```
categories = json.loads(row[1].decode(errors='ignore))     # ignore all non ascii characters
```

Comment: excellent!!  Thanks for your help.  I went with `ignore` as those characters create problems later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have certain non-ascii characters in your csv content.

```
import re

def remove_unicode(text):
    if not text:
        return text

    if isinstance(text, str):
        text = str(text.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    else:
        text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    remove_ctrl_chars_regex = re.compile(r'[^\x20-\x7e]')

    return remove_ctrl_chars_regex.sub('', text)

...
vendorId = remove_unicode(row[0])
...
categories = json.loads(remove_unicode(row[1]))
```

Comment: tried it.  now get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 67-68: invalid continuation byte` referencing the following line `for row in reader:`.

Comment: I think there are some other characters in your csv besides unicode, why not remove them all?

Comment: I'd love to. How do I do that?

Comment: The problem is simply that input encoding is not unicode, so I cannot imagine how the `unicodecsv` module could solve it...

Comment: @dwstein I think reading the entire file and removing the non-ascii characters might be cumbersome. Just ignore non-ascii characters while reading. I have updated my answer. See if it helps.