# Remove null from csv file with non-ascii char

Tags: python, csv, non-ascii-characters

I have a csv file contains null in it. The file also has non-ascii character. I want to have a function to able to handle this kindle of file
so far I tried couple ways, but none of them work
Frist. I tried to `replace('\0', '')` it works for file with ascii but not for `cp1254`
Second I tried unicodecsv module, but it gives me `Error: line contains NULL byte` 
Third try, create `itr = (line.replace('\0') for line in fileObj)` and than pass generator to unicodecsv, but it still raise exception since the `self.reader.next()` in unicodecsv try to get element from generator but it has encoding issue.

for me, those issues like deadlock I need to solve first issue enable to process second one issue, but enable to solve first one I have to get second one work. no clue how to handle those issue. please help. thank you

> UnicodeEncodeError

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
  itr = (line.replace('\0', '') for line in f)
  csv.DictReader(itr)
```

> Error: line contains NULL byte

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
  unicodecsv.DictReader(itr, encoding='cp1254')
```

> UnicodeEncodeError

```
with io.open(path, 'r', encoding=''cp1254) as f:
  itr = (line.replace('\0', '') for line in f)
  csv.DictReader(itr)
```

Comment: check start of the file for BOM header (3 bytes). Then are you sure that there aren't any other strange chars beside nul char?

Comment: So, `csvreader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in csvfile)` doesn't work ?

Comment: for this file, I know where the null is and also know where non-ascii char is, but I want to come up a function to handle it in the future

Comment: @pygo since there is non-ascii char, it will raise a  unicodeencodeerror

Comment: @galaxyan,  there is bug with this csv module , worth to see [here_github](https://github.com/turicas/rows/issues/273)

Comment: @pygo the null char can be either handle by replace it or using utf-16, but I couldn't do either of them, since there is non-ascii char (cp1254)

Comment: @galaxyan, i see! however  you can see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457277/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv-file-using-python)

Comment: @pygo ideally I don't want to modify data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180819/discussion-between-pygo-and-galaxyan).

Comment: The first thing to know about any text file is the character encoding. Which did the author choose? Can you ask them?

Comment: @TomBlodget the file uses cp1254

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 solution tested with one embedded null character and one character from cp1254 that is invalid in utf-8:

```
import csv

# create test file
lines = ['a,b,c,d,e', 
    '1,2,"3,000.26",\u00CExx,5',
    '6,7\x00,800.08,aaa,10']
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='cp1254', newline='') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + '\r\n')

# solution
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1254', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(line.replace('\0', '') for line in f)
    # print rows to show it works
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

outputs

```
OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3,000.26'), ('d', 'Ïxx'), ('e', '5')])
OrderedDict([('a', '6'), ('b', '7'), ('c', '800.08'), ('d', 'aaa'), ('e', '10')])
```